# conditionals on object javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, conditional-statements

I would ask about best practice for conditionals on objects in JS.

fexp:

```
if (a.b.c.d == 1)
```

but if i don't know if that object has correct structure i need to do conditional like this:

```
if(a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d && a.b.c.d == 1)
```

is it best way to check values? Try catch only? Universal method like this:

[javascript test for existence of nested object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key)

is not best way because i need to change definition of my conditionals. I can;t use in this example rules like this:
    if (a.b[1].c.d)

i need remember about all path, channge to string etc...

I am looking for good solution my first conditionals:
    if (a.b.c.d ==1 )

without change it or changed it in simply way like
    if (is(a.b.c.d) == 1)

try catch are ok but no for big body of conditionals :(

Comment: why not just use `if(a.b.c.d && a.b.c.d == 1){ // work Magic }` ?

Comment: @Pogrindis if `b` is not defined it throw `ReferenceError`, @KimYu see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973300/can-i-use-the-in-keyword-to-test-a-property-in-an-tree-object/25973403#25973994

Comment: @Pogrindis put that into js console and find out why not

Comment: One might argue that if you're accessing properties that deeply, your code may need to be refactored somewhat

Comment: Yup.. Friday lapse in common sense!

Comment: :-) thx. i hoped is better solution than dedicated method, thx @Hacketo

Comment: Oh but it's still not good solution - I can't check in this way arrays or variables whitch is defined in this way ( a.b.c[0].d)

Comment: @KimYu this should work with  `a.b.c.0.d` (or make a more generic function that accept array notation)

Comment: @Hacketo yeah - but it simple what where my object key has name "dada-lala" i cant use in this dot notation ;)

Comment: @KimYu what's wrong with `a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d === 1`? Other than the fact it hurts my eyes...it would do what you want.

Comment: why not _.get? https://lodash.com/docs#get

Answer (score 0):

You could just check every value and keep checking until you run out of depth. I have written a little helper function below that will automate this process:

```
function checkDeep(object){
    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        if(typeof object[arguments[i]] !== "undefined"){
            /* Check the type of the nested value - if not undefined,
             * set it to `object` and continue looping. */
            object = object[arguments[i]]
        } else {
            /* If it is not undefined, return false. */
            return false;
        }
    }
    /* If we made it past the loop, all the values exist and we return true. */
    return true;
}
```

You can add as many variables to this as you like at the end and see if they are nested within the previous value. If it hits a break in the chain anywhere, it will return false. So its definition would be:

```
checkDeep(object, var1[, var2, var3, ...]);
```

It would be called as such:

```
checkDeep({a:{b:{c:['d']}}}, 'a', 'b', 'c'); // true
checkDeep({a:{b:{c:['d']}}}, 'a', 'c', 'c'); // false
```

If you want the value at that position, just `return object` at the end of the function instead of `return true`.

```js
function checkDeep(object){
    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        if(typeof object[arguments[i]] != 'undefined') object = object[arguments[i]]
        else return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var object = {a:{b:{c:['d']}}};

document.write("Order a,c,c in '{a:{b:{c:['d']}}}' is " + (checkDeep(object, 'a', 'c', 'c') ? "true" : "false") + "<br />");
checkDeep(object, 'a', 'c', 'c'); // false

document.write("Order a,b,c in '{a:{b:{c:['d']}}}' is " + (checkDeep(object, 'a', 'b', 'c') ? "true" : "false") + "<br />");
checkDeep(object, 'a', 'b', 'c'); // true
```

Comment: bad... i don't need function with few arguments - i have one simply bad path:
    a.b.c.d
bad = because object "a" hasn't key "b" that's all

so i wanna use only this path a.b.c.d = wrong object and take it in exp function witch give me false or true

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
function get_value(variable, elements) {
   if (elements.length === 0) {
      return variable;
   }
   var key = elements.shift();
   return variable[key] && get_value(variable[key], elements); 
}

var a={b:{c:{d:{e:24}}}}

console.log(get_value(a, ['b','c','d','e'])) //24

console.log(get_value(a, ['b','c','d','e', 'f'])) //undefined
```

Only for check if the value exist:

```
function check(variable, elements) {
   if (elements.length === 0) {
      return true;
   }
   var key = elements.shift();
   return variable[key] !== undefined && check(variable[key], elements); 
}
```

Comment: Maybe a sneak a peek approach would be more convenient. Like just returning `true` or `false` if you can access safely or not the asked keys

Comment: I don't think that you really need, but i added the code option.

Comment: bad... i don't need function with few arguments - i have one simply bad path:
    a.b.c.d
bad = because object "a" hasn't key "b" that's all

so i wanna use only this path a.b.c.d = wrong object and take it in exp function witch give me false or true

Comment: and one more things how in your example i will check this value:

if(a.b['oo-dd-zz'][3].c.d.e){}

Comment: in  var a={b:{c:[{d:{e:24}}]}}   you can  console.log(get_value(a, ['b','c', 0 ,'d','e'])) You can add the index

Comment: get_value(a, ['b','oo-dd-zz','3','c','d','e'])

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeScript has the existential operator:

```
a?.b?.c?.d
```

There is an extensive disucssion on this topic, also called the "null propagation operator", on the ES6 discuss list at https://esdiscuss.org/topic/existential-operator-null-propagation-operator.